# Do I need to check out and check in again in transit airport?

Tags: transit, qatar-airways, us-airways, philadelphia

I am flying from Atlanta to Dhaka. I bought the ticket from Qatar airways. My flight is :

Atlanta --- Philadelphia (operated by US airways)

Philadelphia --- Doha (Qatar airways)

Doha --- Dhaka (Qatar airways)

Do I need to collect my bag in Philadelphia as they are under different airways, though I booked it together?

Comment: For codeshare flights, no, in my experience.

Comment: On a single booking your bags should be checked through all the way to DAC.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my experience tells me, that it is mostly not a matter of the airline. At least in Europe it works pretty well beyond airline, international and intercontinental flights.
From my travel experience in Asia, once you change from national to international flights, it happens fairly frequent that you have to collect your luggage.

What I remember, if you entering US from abroad, you'll always have to pick up your luggage before connecting flight.

So I guess you'll only know if you ask the clerk at the baggage drop.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I'm not sure this answers the question, since the OP is flying US - Qatar - Bangladesh and you mention everything *but* this itinerary. ;)

Comment: Collecting bags on entry to the U.S. is a customs requirement, not a failure of airlines to arrange things properly. However there is no need for a customs inspection when leaving the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sharp question because it depends if the airlines in question have a baggage interline agreement. US and QR do. Your bag should be through-checked to your final destination, in which case you will not see it again until you arrive in Dhaka. However you should check this when you drop off your baggage.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have to collect your bags again. Your bags will be checked in all the way to DAC since you are on a codeshare flight.

Relax, and enjoy your (long) trip. Qatar Airways has some really good food and the newly revamped airport in Doha is also very nice.